# Is there a way to run benchmarks with failing tests?

Tags: testing, go, benchmarking

Is it expected that benchmarks don't run unless all tests in the package have passed.

I've looked at the [testing package doc](https://golang.org/pkg/testing) and the [testing flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags) and I can't find it documented that benchmarks run only after all tests pass.

Is there a way to force benchmark functions to run even when some tests in the package have failed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can skip the failing tests using the `-run` flag, or choose to run none at all

```
go test -bench . -run NONE
```

Comment: I suppose -run none should work. Is this pre-condition to running benchmarks documented or is it so obvious it doesn't need any ?

Comment: It actually is obvious.

Comment: @Sridhar: I never read closely, but I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior. For all failure methods, the docs state: `Execution will continue at the next test or benchmark`, which makes it sound like benchmarks should continue.